# VHDL coding error "Else clause after check for clock not supported"

Tags: if-statement, vhdl, vivado

I'm trying to make a counter that sends out a carry signal after every 64 clock pulses. When I try to synthesize the code shown below, (in Vivado) I get the following error,

> Else clause after check for clock not supported.

*(On the line signaled with the '!!')*

I did something very similar in a different project and I did not get any error there, so I don't really get what's wrong. Any help?

```
entity refresh_counter is
     port( CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
           CLR : in STD_LOGIC;
           CARRY : out STD_LOGIC);
end refresh_counter;

architecture Behavioral of refresh_counter is
begin

process(CLK)
variable tel : integer;
begin
    if (CLK'event and CLK = '1') then
        if CLR = '1' then
            tel := 0;
        end if;
    else
        if (tel < 63) then            !!
            tel := tel + 1;
        else
            CARRY <= '1';
            tel := 0;
        end if;
    end if;

end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Your `else` tries to describe what happens at all times that there is *not* a rising edge of `clk`. How would you imagine this being implemented in real hardware?

Comment: Honestly I don't really know how this would be implemented in real hardware and maybe thats the problem. I do think I get the point however. I moved the else loop inside the `if CLR = '1' then ` loop and now it synthesizes.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to write `elsif (tel < 63) then`, that makes more sense than having the first `else` on the `if` CLK part.  Btw. you also want to clear the `CARRY` at some time.  Finally, consider make `tel` a signal instead, since that makes simulation debugging easier.

Comment: @MortenZilmer Good call on the `CARRY` clear. Completely overlooked that.

Comment: You might also want to use the `rising_edge` function as a more robust and readable way of detecting edges: `if (rising_edge(clk)) then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @scary_jeff in the comments section, your `else` doesn't make sense as you cannot practically implement *not at rising edge*. Here is an implementation that will do the job.

The process has two variables `n_carry` and `n_tel`. You can treat them like the combinational output of the FSM. On the clock's rising edge, these two variables are transferred to `carry` and `tel` respectively.

In the case `CLR` is high, `0` will be transferred instead.

The `n_carry` and `n_tel` logic is implemented combinationally in hardware. It takes `tel` as an input and the decision making has been coded in the `if-elsif-else` sequence in the process.

```
library std;
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity refresh_counter is
     port( CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
           CLR : in STD_LOGIC;
           CARRY : out STD_LOGIC);
end refresh_counter;

architecture Behavioral of refresh_counter is
signal tel: integer := 0;
begin

process(CLK, CLR, tel)
variable n_tel: integer := 0;
variable n_carry: STD_LOGIC := '0';
begin

    if (tel < 63) then
        n_carry := '0';
        n_tel := tel + 1;
    elsif (tel = 63) then
        n_carry := '1';
        n_tel := 0;
    else
        -- This case should never arise in practice
        n_carry := '0';
        n_tel := 0;
    end if;

    if (CLK'event and CLK = '1') then
        if CLR = '1' then
            tel <= 0;
            CARRY <= '0';
        else
            tel <= n_tel;
            CARRY <= n_carry;
        end if;
    end if;

end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: A more standard way of writing this would be to put the required code inside the `if(clk'event ...` part. All he actually needed to do was to move the first `end if` to the end, and add an assignment of `CARRY <= '0'` after `tel := tel + 1;` . From the comments, it looks like this is what he did.